# inhabilitar lista de opciones chosen Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Buenas

tengo un campo chosen y querria habilitar/inhabilitar la lista de opciones en funcion de unas variables, he usado el siguiente codigo y no funciona, a ver si alguien puede orientarme.

JS:

```
$(".chosen").chosen({max_selected_options: 5});
$(".chosen").bind("chosen:maxselected", function () { alert("AAA");});
```

html:

```
<select id="Selecion" class="chosen" multiple="multiple" onclick="$('#Seleccion').trigger('chosen:open');" data-placeholder="Lista" class="chosen-select" style=" width:200px; padding: 7px 18px 6px 9px;" tabindex="24">
```

Comment: Solucionado: el problema es que chosen (https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) no admite modificacion una vez creado, asi que la solucion es destruirlo y crearlo de nuevo con los valores actualizados.     $(".chosen").chosen("destroy");
$('.chosen').chosen({
 max_selected_options: NEW_VAR
});

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a añadir esta línea justo después para obligar a que actualice.

```
$('.chosen').trigger("chosen:updated");
```